# Rhel: Get machine ID and then replace it in file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, rhel, rhel7

I have machineid in /etc/machine-id

I want to replace string

id=machineid in file /var/somefile.conf

with the "new id".

How can I do this easy with one command line?

Comment: Maybe this `sed -i  's/machineid/'$(cat /etc/machine-id)'/' /var/somefile.conf`

Comment: do you still need an answer?